# Adding a font to angular application

Tags: css, angular, webpack, fonts

I'm trying to add a font to an angular application without much success. I created the font in Adobe Illustrator and converted it to a font using an online web conversion. The font is working in the demo file they sent back so I'm sure that the font works.

However, when Webpack compiles the angular application I get an error that says CssSyntaxError. the full error is:

> ERROR in ./src/app/icons/poker-fonts/style.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--15-3!./src/app/icons/poker-fonts/style.scss)
>   Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: C:\Users\James\source\repos\range-analizer\src\app\icons\poker-fonts\style.scss:4:2: Can't resolve 'fonts/pokericon.woff' in 'C:\Users\James\source\repos\range-analizer\src\app\icons\poker-fonts'

and I cannot figure this out.

this is the part that it's failing on:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'pokericon';
  src:  url('fonts/pokericon.eot');
  src:  url('fonts/pokericon.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/pokericon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/pokericon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/pokericon.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: block;
}
```

Comment: move your `scsc` to `assets` folder, and move your fonts to `assets/fonts` folder, then include them (e.g. within styles.scss or where it does make sense).

Comment: @Lonely I did this and I'm getting the same error, what does the name matter?

Comment: that's either an url-problem (your scss/fonts folder are not accessible, are you running an http-server, did you create the project with @angular/cli?) or your webpack config is not OK. Can you put it into codesandbox?

Comment: Yes I created the project with Cli

Comment: that did it! thank you!